# Correctly redirect bot requests to static version of a website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, bots

I'm having problems getting my website to index correctly by Google.

## My folder structure looks like this:

```
root
 - cms
 - www
```

example.com points to the root where a .htaccess routes all requests to /www:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]
```

## Front end

The Angular front end inside /www gets data from /cms via REST api. So far so good.

What I want to achieve is that bots don't crawl inside my ajaxified /www page but instead inside /cms where I print out static contents corresponding to the URL structure in /www.

## URL for static content:

/www/test1 -> Outputs nice content via REST

/cms/test1 -> Outputs text-only content for the crawler

## Bot redirect

I'm redirecting the bots coming to example.com/www to /cms like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/cms/$1 [R=301,L]
```

## Site map

I also registered a sitemap with Google with the following contents:

```
http://www.example/test1
http://www.example/test2
and so on...
```

## The problem

This all works fine BUT: Google is also crawling the static contents inside /cms without being redirected there by me. I only want this static subdomain to be fed through the redirect but not when Google's bot is searching for it itself. Kind of "disallowing" the bot to crawl here - but in the other hand I NEED it to crawl it. A catch 22 in my opinion.

## Edit: complete .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

# Sitemap
RewriteRule ^sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.xml(\.gz)?$ /cms/sitemap$1.xml$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\.html(\.gz)?$ /cms/sitemap$1.xml$2 [L]

# Redirect bots to static pages
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/cms/$1 [R=301,L]

# Angular HTML5 mode: Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index

# Angular HTML5 mode: Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule (.*) /www/index.html [L]
```

## Edit 2

I have added this tag to the www page

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

to let the crawler know there's AJAX being used on the page. And I'm using the rewrite suggest by @Croises but in reaction to Google's _escaped_fragment_ re-request. Let's wait a few days...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Did you put your `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot...` before `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]` ? Otherwise it is never used... (add all your .htaccess [edit])

Comment: @Croises thanks, I have added the whole file. The order is right though I believe.

Comment: If for bots you redirect 301 to `/cms` Why not use directly this link in your site map ? Or rewrite to `/cms` (and not redirect) ? (cloaking ?)

Comment: If I were to use the /cms links in my sitemap this would be a conflict to the end user URLs e.g. www.example.com/test1 meaning www.example.com/www/test1, right? I haven't tried a rewrite - sounds promising though. What do you mean by cloaking?

Comment: And for my, you have a problem with your sitemap rewrite if the name is `sitmap-1.xml` (try to change final [L] to [R] to debug and see the final link) I think you try to add final .gz but it's `$3`.

Comment: The cloaking... yes, it's what you try to do. Read that: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en

Comment: I'm confused. I read that Google is actually endorsing this technique: http://odino.org/how-to-make-your-javascript-apps-seo-friendly/

Comment: The cloaking is not prohibited, it is just very dangerous, especially if what you try to display is not like the "real" content, and highly optimized for search engines...

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect to static page, and ask them to index or reference the final page without crawling the "real" content.

You can rewrite your link:

```
# Rewrite bots to static pages
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms/$1 [L]
```

Just without `R=301`. Like that you show the page without redirection.
But beware of cloaking ([Google and Cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en)).